# AppWidgetHostView can't handle any click events?

Tags: android

I am creating an android launcher and want to implement appWidgets. For testing, I am using the `com.android.quicksearchbox` widget and adding it to the top of the screen.
Problem is, I am using AppWidgetHostView and it seems not to notice any click or touch events the user does. Can anybody tell me why ? Here is all my code for appWidgets (in the `onCreate(Bundle)` function) :

```
    android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
    android.appwidget.AppWidgetHost appWidgetHost = new android.appwidget.AppWidgetHost(this, 0);
    android.appwidget.AppWidgetProviderInfo newAppWidgetProviderInfo = new android.appwidget.AppWidgetProviderInfo();


    int appWidgetId = appWidgetHost.allocateAppWidgetId();


    List<android.appwidget.AppWidgetProviderInfo> appWidgetInfos = new ArrayList<android.appwidget.AppWidgetProviderInfo>();
    appWidgetInfos = appWidgetManager.getInstalledProviders();

    for(int j = 0; j < appWidgetInfos.size(); j++)
    {
        if (appWidgetInfos.get(j).provider.getPackageName().equals("com.android.quicksearchbox"))
        {

            newAppWidgetProviderInfo = appWidgetInfos.get(j);
            break;
        }
     }



    android.appwidget.AppWidgetHostView hostView = appWidgetHost.createView(this, appWidgetId, newAppWidgetProviderInfo);
    hostView.setAppWidget(appWidgetId, newAppWidgetProviderInfo);


    android.widget.LinearLayout ll = (android.widget.LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.loll);
    ll.addView(hostView, 0);
```

loll is my LinearLayout.

So anybody knows how can I enable events ? Or if there is another method of adding app-widgets to my launcher ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I am  not  sure  the code is complete ,  but   you  need to add  at least  the following in your activity .

```
@Override
 protected void onStart() {

    super.onStart();

    Host.startListening();

}



@Override

protected void onStop() {

    super.onStop();

    Host.stopListening();

}
```

Does this make sense?

Comment: I tried your solution seems to work, but the problem that with the complex widgets in which I have to see data near http or that of messages or gmail the data do not see them

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the widget to make it interactive and allow it to update:

```
boolean allowed = mAppWidgetManager.bindAppWidgetIdIfAllowed(appWidgetId, newAppWidgetProviderInfo.provider);

if (!allowed) {
    // Request permission
    Intent intent = new Intent(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_BIND);
    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_PROVIDER, newAppWidgetProviderInfo.provider);
    final int REQUEST_BIND_WIDGET = 1987;
    myActivity.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_BIND_WIDGET);
}
```

Additionally, as mentioned in @Sergey's response, you need to add the following in your activity or fragment:

```
@Override
 protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    appWidgetHost.startListening();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    appWidgetHost.stopListening();
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution seems to work, but the problem that with the complex widgets in which I have to see data near http or that of messages or gmail the data do not see them.